# status of 404 POST after used HttpContext.Current.Request.Form Web API

Tags: ajax, post, asp.net-web-api2, http-status-code-404

I have Ajax POST to Web API in MVC

```js
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('idGuid', func.WpPluginManager.Identity);
    formData.append('userName', func.modalElement.userName.val());

    var url = func.info.loadArray.IsLocalVersion === true ? '/api/Widget/PostDataWidget/' : func.dataArray.serverUrl + '/api/Widget/PostDataWidget/';

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: formData,
        crossDomain: true,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            debugger
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err.responseJSON);
        }

    });
```

And I have POST HttpResponseMessage in Web API Controller

```js
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("api/Widget/PostDataWidget/")]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostDataWidget()
    {
        if (Request == null) { return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest); }
        try
        {
            var idGuid = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.Get("idGuid");
            var userName = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.Get("userName");

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Implement ex
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Everything is fine. I can pass data from Ajax POST to my Web Api Controller.
This is my Form in Request in Web API Controller:
[image]

But when i try to get value by key:

var idGuid = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.Get("idGuid");

I take 404 error in Ajax POST.

[HttpException]: The controller for path '/Widget/PostDataWidget/' was not found or does not implement IController.
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
-->

Where could be the problem. What did I do wrong?

p.S: WebApiConfig in Global.asax registration firstly.

Answer (score 0):

I found what was the error.

This Ajax post located in click event for my buton.I added buton to form. Form was empty and form has no action method and type method.

This button has typ: submit. When I changed type from submit to button my Ajax POST then worked.